# How to create a jQuery Mobile Popup Alert mechanism?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have been trying for hours to implement this and I am close but not there.

The goal is simple. To have a functional popup alert that can be used from everywhere within an app.

For example I have some code where I want to show a popup after a simple if test:

```
if (message.type == "Error") { //lets show a popup !!!

    $.mobile.changePage( "alert.html", {
    type: "post", 
    data: "alert_title="+message.type+"&alert_message="+message.content,
    transition: "pop",
    role: "dialog",
    reloadPage:true
});
```

As you can see I am passing in some custom data.

Here is the code for my alert page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Alert</title>
        <!--#include virtual="header.inc" -->

    <script>
    alert("test");
    $('#alert_dialog').live('pageinit', function (event) {
    $("#alert_title").text($.urlParam('alert_title'));
    $("#alert_body").text($.urlParam('alert_message'));
    });
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="alert_dialog">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Alert</h1>

        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <h1 id="alert_title">alert title</h1>
            <p id="alert_body">alert body</p>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back">OK</a>        
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

The problem I am running is that no javascript is getting executed on `alerts.html` page since it is injected to the DOM. Why would jQuery Mobile even allow us to send POST data using  `$.mobile.changePage` when we cannot possibly use it?

Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Use this, it is JQM based popup like the Toast message on android.

https://gist.github.com/3136584

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:

Looks like this should be in 1.2 release:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html

I know this really doesn't answer your question but the jQM Team thinks this should be ready for version 1.2 release:

- http://filamentgroup.com/tests/popup/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Posted on the jQM blog:

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/26/jquery-mobile-1-0-1-released/

Comment: That would be totally cool however I have a release next week that I have to get completed. I can see using that in next iteration but not sure what to do here .

Comment: @jini Looks like this should be in 1.2 release:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Comment: I coundnt find the planed release dete for 1.2 final.  I know its in Alpha now, but I think its not ready for production.  Does anyone know if there is a release plan ?   Thanks